# Magento blank page frontend

Tags: magento, xampp

Good Morning, I'm trying to install a Magento theme on my localhost(XAMPP).

The theme is Sahara responsive.

I followed the guide and I installed it, but when i went to the frontend the homepage was blank.

I tried to clean the cache but it was useless. I switched to the Luma theme and it works. How can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

To help you debug the issue, try turning on error printing in your index.php

```
/**
 * Error reporting
 */
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
```

You can also try setting this if the above doesn't help:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```